# DocuSign sandbox connection is getting an sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: docusignapi, sslv3

All of my connections to the DocuSign sandbox are getting this curl error:

error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I have only noticed this today, and can't remember the last time I checked the sandbox connection so I couldn't say when this first broke.

Comment: It looks like this might be due to SSL3 being disabled by DocuSign because of POODLE. Not sure what to do to fix it, however, and/or if it is also an issue with the live connections.

Comment: [DocuSign issued an alert on Feb 13, 2015](https://trust.docusign.com/updates-and-alerts). SSLv3 was disabled in the sandbox on Feb 23, and will be disabled in production on March 23. I feel like a guest who arrived at a party too early, and the snacks haven't been put out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific to PHP, I changed the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION from this:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

to this:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1)
```

and the API is functional again.